# Атрибут class. Максимальное значение имен

Tags: html, классы

Атрибут class="" может иметь несколько стилевых значений. А какое максимальное кол-во их может быть для тега?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В HTML5 нет никакого ограничения в количестве классов для тега. Вы ограничены только памятью браузера.

Вот интересная [статья](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/maximum-number-of-supported-classes-per-element/) о том, какие ограничения есть у различных браузеров. Если коротко, то у автора не получилось дойти до какого-то "максимума" из-за скорости выполнения скрипта. Скрипт в некоторых браузерах дошёл до 4000.

В HTML4 есть ограничение на длину атрибута. Но, в действительности, до этого ограничения дойти тоже довольно сложно.

Comment: спасибки)) терь я спокоен, и могу сделать задуманное :)